# Jenkins and MSBuild Error

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am having an issue with building a sln on Jenkins. I know what the problem is I just have no idea how to fix said problem. So the sln imports a project that is not located in the same folder as the sln. This is not an issue with other sln files that we do the same thing with. As you can see below instead of .. to get back to parent directory it is a looking for a .. directory which obviously doesn't exist.

```
 D:\Path\To\sln\OurSolution.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file 
"D:\Path\To\sln\..\..\PathTo\SharedProject\Shared.csproj" was not found
[D:\Path\To\sln\OurSolution.sln]
```

Comment: updated my answer based on your comment below.  Do you have absolute paths in your csproj files?  Is that why it is working on your local machine and not the Jenkins build server?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .sln file and have it point to the .csproj file that does exist.

Also, double check your working directory to make sure it's the directory where the solution exists.

Comment: The sln does point to the correct csproj. I can run and build locally. Something happens when Jenkins runs it though.

Answer (score 0):

Paths in the .sln file need to be relative to the location of the .sln file so that when Jenkins can checks out the entire solution into its workspace from source control the paths resolve.

- Check that the paths in the solution file are indeed relative to the solution file.
- Check that all the project files defined in the solution file (and all their files in turn) are indeed being checked out to the Jenkins job workspace folder.

Where is the shared project in source control in relation to your solution file?  Is it in the same repository?  If it isn't then my bet is your Jenkins job isn't checking it out from source control into its workspace and therefore not finding it when the solution tries to compile.

Paths your sln and csproj files are relative.  .sln and .csproj files paths are relative from where the sit on the file system.

Usually you would expect csproj files to exist in immediate subdirectories of the directory where the .sln file sits.